# Line Notes for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way by which I can add a useful message to a line in VS Code Editor which is not written in code but is like a note (Similar to like comments on a line in a Pull Request in Git) which can be deleted later on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the two extensions that I came across, hope this helps:

1). Line Note: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tkrkt.linenote

2). Code Annotation: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tkcandrade.code-annotation

I preferred **Code Annotation** for it's seemingly active org admin and the team of contributors and for marking notes as DONE or PENDING feature.

Answer (score 5):

The "Line note" extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tkrkt.linenote is probably what you are looking for…

Answer (score -2):

Many languages allow you to append a comment to the end of a line. In python for example, you could have the following:

import numpy as np
a = 13.6 # a is the density of material

anser = a * b # where b is the volume in meters/cubic centimeters
...

Do not know what your language is but maybe this could work.

Comment: Check comments on first answer.

Answer (score -3):

Comments can be added to code based on what language you are using. They are not specfic to the editor for the most part.

For example, in C++ you can comment by putting double slashes before the line such as `// Random Comment`.

Look up the commenting syntax for whatever code language you are using.

Comment: I didn't mean comment in code but I mean short message added to a particular line (like notes at that line).

Comment: Why would you need to if you can comment directly onto the line or to the one after? Wouldn't it serve the same purpose and be be more transferable between editors?

Comment: No, It would change the codebase. Consider the situation when I have multiple lines to discuss with some person later. It's difficult to remember them all and changing codebase would add a headache of removing it back and the method would not stilll solve the problem.

Comment: Then I do not believe there is something like to what you are looking for, sorry.

Comment: I think there must be an extension for this. :/